# SUP Error: 571 Detail: Session failed Source: in iOS

Tags: ios, sup, smp

im developing ios native application using sup 2.1.3 (SUP server). but i'm getting below error while  registering the device in sybase control center .I have searched for this but i didn't get any solutions..can any one help me how to solve this?

**My Code:**

```
SUPConnectionProfile *sp = [self.connectionProfile syncProfile];
        [sp setDomainName:@"default"];
        [sp setServerName:@"john-PC"];
        [sp setPortNumber:2480];
        [sp setNetworkProtocol:@"http,https"];
        [sp setNetworkStreamParams:@"trusted_certificates=;url_suffix="];
        [sp applyPropertiesFromApplication];



code for registering the device :


@try
{
SUPApplication* app = [SUPApplication getInstance];
[app registerApplication:120]; // here i'm increasing to 60 10 120


    @catch (SUPApplicationTimeoutException* tex)
    {
        NSLog(@"SUPApplicationTimeoutException");
        NSLog(@"%@: %@--%@", [tex name],[tex message], [tex description]);
        [self.loader hide:YES];

    }
    @catch (SUPPersistenceException * pe) {
        NSLog(@"SUPPersistenceException");
        NSLog(@"%@: %@", [pe name],[pe message]);
        [self showNoTransportAlert:kSUP102ErrorFailure];
    }
}
```

**Error Console:**

```
2014-03-25 14:12:49.085 SUP102[1891:6303] =================================================
2014-03-25 14:12:49.085 SUP102[1891:6303] onConnectionStatusChanged: status = 105, code = 571, message = Error: 571 Detail: Session failed Source: /Users/iotabuilder/svn/Pioneer/MOClients/iPhone/../Common/C/moClient.cpp 1024.
2014-03-25 14:12:49.086 SUP102[1891:6303] =================================================
2014-03-25 14:12:49.087 SUP102[1891:6303] =================================================
2014-03-25 14:12:49.087 SUP102[1891:6303] onConnectionStatusChanged: status = 105, code = 571, message = Error: 571 Detail: Session failed Source: /Users/iotabuilder/svn/Pioneer/MOClients/iPhone/../Common/C/moClient.cpp 1024.
2014-03-25 14:12:49.087 SUP102[1891:6303] =================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the standard Example for registration:

```
SUPApplication* app = [SUPApplication getInstance];
[app setApplicationIdentifier:@"YOURAPPIdentifier"];

MyApplicationCallbackHandler *ch = [MyApplicationCallbackHandler getInstance]; 
[app setApplicationCallback:ch];
SUPConnectionProperties* props = app.connectionProperties;

[props setServerName:@"supserver.mycompany.com"];
[props setPortNumber:5001]; // the messaging 

SUPLoginCredentials* login = [SUPLoginCredentials getInstance];
login.username = @"username";
login.password = @"password";
props.loginCredentials = login;
[app registerApplication:120]; // 120 second timeout for registration
```

Don't set protocol, domain, network stream parameter etc...

Comment: Thanks for your reply..i solved issue Which happing because i am unable connect SUP server ipAddress from my device..